# Failed to close socket handle with ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE (6)

Tags: python, windows-ce, ctypes, winsock2

I am working with winsock2 socket in ctypes, I can do `closesocket()` just fine, but calling CloseHandle, always result in `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE (6)`. How should I close it properly ? Currently my app always crash after 64 times of socket() calls.

```
# from MSDN:
# BOOL CloseHandle(   HANDLE hObject);

closehandle = coredll.CloseHandle
closehandle.argtypes = [ w.LPVOID ]

SOCKET = c_ulong
socket = ws2.socket
socket.restype = SOCKET
self._clnt_socket = socket(AF_BT, SOCK_STREAM, BTHPROTO_RFCOMM)
...
connect( self._clnt_socket, _psa, sizeof(self._sa) )
...
send( self._clnt_socket, pbuff, szbuff, 0 ) # int send(  SOCKET s,  const char FAR* buf,  int len,  int flags);

SetLastError(0)
rt = closesocket( self._clnt_socket )
ec = GetLastError()
if ec != w.ERROR_SUCCESS :
    print( u'failed to close socket, ec=%s, %s, rt=%s', (ec, FormatError( ec ), rt) )
    raise Exception(u'BT_SOCKET.close.socket %s' % ec)
else:
    print( u'close socket ok' )
#> close socket ok

# from MSDN:
# To close the connection to the target device, call the closesocket
# function to close the Bluetooth socket. Also, ensure that you release
# the socket by calling the CloseHandle function, as the following
# example code shows.  
#
# closesocket(client_socket); 
# CloseHandle((LPVOID)client_socket);

SetLastError(0)
rt = closehandle(  w.LPVOID( self._clnt_socket ) )
ec = GetLastError()
if ec != w.ERROR_SUCCESS :
    print( u'failed to close handle, ec=%s, %s, rt=%s ', (ec, FormatError( ec ), rt) )
    # //Perform error handling.
    raise Exception(u'BT_SOCKET.close.handle %s' % ec)
else:
    print( u'close socket ok' )
#> failed to close handle, ec=6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*HANDLE*s and *SOCKET*s are different types of *objects*, so they are incompatible (applies to their *Python* wrappers as well).

Here's what [[MS.Docs]: CloseHandle function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/handleapi/nf-handleapi-closehandle) states:

> Do not use the **CloseHandle** function to close a socket. Instead, **use the [closesocket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/winsock/nf-winsock-closesocket) function**, which releases all resources associated with the socket including the handle to the socket object. For more information, see [Socket Closure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/WinSock/graceful-shutdown-linger-options-and-socket-closure-2).

***@EDIT0***:

- The above applies to "normal" *Win*. [[MS.Docs]: CloseHandle (Windows CE 5.0)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/aa517300(v=msdn.10)) doesn't specify that paragraph, and also mentions that it can be used on *Socket*s.
- [[MS.Docs]: socket (Windows Sockets) (Windows CE 5.0)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/aa450958%28v%3dmsdn.10%29) states:

  > When a session has been completed, a [closesocket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/ms887908%28v%3dmsdn.10%29) call must be performed.
- [[MS.Docs]: Creating a Connection to a Remote Device Using Winsock (Windows CE 5.0)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/ms881660%28v=msdn.10%29) does indeed specify to call *CloseHandle* but only in step ***#5*** for client socket (neither in step ***#4***, nor for server socket), which makes me think that it's an error (*WinCE* pages are full of errors - at least typos)

As a side question: why are you using *ctypes* instead of [[Python 3]: socket - Low-level networking interface](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) which is a wrapper over *WinSock*? It's like shooting yourself in the foot. If the *BT* sockets work identically like others (e.g. network), the only thing you have to do is define some constants (e.g. *BTHPROTO_RFCOMM*).

Comment: Ok, I think you are right, after cleaning out the close handle stuff. I can open/write/close the socket more then 64 times without crash, though its against what this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/ms881660%28v=msdn.10%29) MSDN artical suggested ... As to the python socket, I don't know, if python will check the parameter and stop me from using the unknown parameters ? I'll try, if that works, it would be surely great.

Comment: Ah, I keep forgetting about this *WindowsCE* and its limitations. However it seems strange to call `CloseHandle` on `SOCKET`, as on 64 bit it has a greater size thath `HANDLE`.

Comment: Thank you for looking into it. I have tried python socket I can't get it to connect. the `socekt` 's `connect()` method doesn't accept my bt address neither `int('dc1d30428b19',16)`, `'dc1d30428b19'`, nor `'dc:1d:30:42:8b:19'`. I guess the module has to be patched. But I'v get over the major road blocks, now its somehow stable; unicode works fine; Now I can focus on the GUI, I hope it works with thread. Again thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, *Python*'s wrapper expects a tuple (string, int) containing the host name and port.